# Ubuntu Server: dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: server, apt, dpkg

I have experienced this error in the past but have been able to resolve it by running 'sudo apt-get -f install'; however, that is no longer the case.  I have spent about 4 hours looking into this and would greatly appreciate any help!

Terminal output:

It all started when I tried to install the unoconv package:

```
patrick@SERVER01:~$ sudo apt-get install unoconv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.2 is to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1) but 5.4.15-1~precise+1 is to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.43.51) but 3.2.0.54.64 is to be installed
 unoconv : Depends: python-uno but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libreoffice-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libreoffice-java-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try to install libreoffice-core or libreoffice-common I get the following output:

```
patrick@SERVER01:~$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.2 is to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1) but 5.4.15-1~precise+1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-common : Depends: libreoffice-style-default or
                               libreoffice-style
                      Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: xfonts-mathml but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libexttextcat-data but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.43.51) but 3.2.0.54.64 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I noticed the server's kernel being mentioned, I will return some output near the end of this post.

Here is the output when I run apt-get -f install

```
patrick@SERVER01:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-mpm-itk initramfs-tools libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libgd3 libjson-c2 liblua5.1-0
  libvpx1 linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic linux-image-server linux-server php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-json php5-mcrypt
  php5-mysql
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom libgd-tools fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools php-pear
  php5-user-cache
Recommended packages:
  php5-readline
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data libgd3 libjson-c2 liblua5.1-0 libvpx1 linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic php5-json
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-itk initramfs-tools libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap linux-image-server linux-server php5-cgi php5-cli
  php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
15 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 2 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
37 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 153 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: apache2.2-common: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 apache2-mpm-itk depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3).
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is to be removed.
(Reading database ... 122179 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2.2-common ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for ufw ...
(Reading database ... 121861 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3 (using .../apache2_2.4.6-3+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/authz_default.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/authn_default.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/mem_cache.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/mem_cache.conf out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/authn_alias.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/cern_meta.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/disk_cache.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/disk_cache.conf out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/ident.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/imagemap.load out of the way...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/version.load out of the way...
Unpacking replacement apache2 ...
Preparing to replace apache2-mpm-itk 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3 (using .../apache2-mpm-itk_2.4.6-3+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
 * Stopping web server apache2                                                                                                                             
 * The apache2 configtest failed, so we are trying to kill it manually. This is almost certainly suboptimal, so please make sure your system is working as you'd expect now!
 ...    waiting                                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
Unpacking replacement apache2-mpm-itk ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
Unpacking apache2-data (from .../apache2-data_2.4.6-3+debphp.org~precise+1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
(Reading database ... 122245 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2.2-bin ...
(Reading database ... 122164 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libaprutil1-ldap 1.3.12+dfsg-3 (using .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.2-1~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libaprutil1-ldap ...
Preparing to replace libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 1.3.12+dfsg-3 (using .../libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.2-1~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 ...
Preparing to replace libaprutil1 1.3.12+dfsg-3 (using .../libaprutil1_1.5.2-1~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libaprutil1 ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblua5.1-0.
Unpacking liblua5.1-0 (from .../liblua5.1-0_5.1.4-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-bin.
Unpacking apache2-bin (from .../apache2-bin_2.4.6-3+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Preparing to replace php5-mysql 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-mysql_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-mysql ...
Preparing to replace php5-cli 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-cli_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-cli ...
Preparing to replace php5-mcrypt 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-mcrypt_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-mcrypt ...
Preparing to replace php5-curl 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-curl_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-curl ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvpx1.
Unpacking libvpx1 (from .../libvpx1_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgd3.
Unpacking libgd3 (from .../libgd3_2.1.0-2~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Preparing to replace php5-gd 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-gd_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-gd ...
Preparing to replace php5-cgi 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-cgi_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Moving obsolete conffile /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5_cgi.load out of the way...
Unpacking replacement php5-cgi ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjson-c2.
Unpacking libjson-c2 (from .../libjson-c2_0.11-3+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Preparing to replace php5-common 5.4.15-1~precise+1 (using .../php5-common_5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-common ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/etc/php5/conf.d': Directory not empty
Selecting previously unselected package php5-json.
Unpacking php5-json (from .../php5-json_1.3.1+dfsg-4+debphp.org~precise+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic_3.2.0-54.82_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic_3.2.0-54.82_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                           dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic_3.2.0-54.82_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Kernel Info:

```
patrick@SERVER01:~$ dpkg --list | grep "linux-*"
ii  libselinux1                      2.1.0-4.1ubuntu1                    SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-firmware                   1.79.6                              Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-53           3.2.0-53.81                         Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic   3.2.0-53.81                         Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-54           3.2.0-54.82                         Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-54-generic   3.2.0-54.82                         Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-server             3.2.0.54.64                         Linux kernel headers on Server Equipment.
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic     3.2.0-23.36                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic     3.2.0-29.46                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic     3.2.0-32.51                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic     3.2.0-33.52                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic     3.2.0-34.53                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic     3.2.0-38.61                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic     3.2.0-39.62                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic     3.2.0-40.64                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic     3.2.0-41.66                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic     3.2.0-43.68                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic     3.2.0-44.69                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-server               3.2.0.43.51                         Linux kernel image on Server Equipment.
iU  linux-libc-dev                   3.2.0-54.82                         Linux Kernel Headers for development
iU  linux-server                     3.2.0.43.51                         Complete Linux kernel on Server Equipment.
ii  util-linux                       2.20.1-1ubuntu3                     Miscellaneous system utilities
```

Thanks you all so much for any help! I'm a high school senior learning as I go :)

Comment: `failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during './boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic': No space left on device`. Solution: free some space on `/boot`. You may do this by `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: When I run apt-get autoremove I get the following: `root@SERVER01:/home/patrick# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.2 is installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.43.51) but 3.2.0.54.64 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@SERVER01:/home/patrick#
`

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I still haven't been able to resolve this! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to free some space manually. Delete old vmlinuz and initrd files from `/boot`

Comment: @Danatela manually never touch the `/boot` partition, the Murphy's Law says that it will mess up.

Comment: I'm seeing that you have 110 upgrades still not applied, please run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and apply the upgrades.